# SingleChildScrollView height to use for containing ConstrainedBox max height- Flutter

Tags: flutter, flutter-dependencies, expand, singlechildscrollview

Is there a way to work out the complete height of a SingleChildScrollView so it can be used setting the ConstrainedBox height.
I have a SingleChildScrollView which contains a number of widgets including columns and an Expanded which can vary in height.
I have tried a number of different techniques including using MediaQuery.of(context).size.height but this only provides a height of the visible screen, not the total height of the not total scrollable area.

child: SingleChildScrollView(
controller: scrollController,
child: ConstrainedBox(
constraints: BoxConstraints(maxHeight: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height+MediaQuery.of(context).size.height),

```
child: Column(
  mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
  children: [
  ConstrainedBox(
    constraints: BoxConstraints(maxHeight: 295, minHeight: 100.0),
    child: PageView.builder(
    itemCount: videObj.results.length,
    controller: PageController(viewportFraction: 0.8, initialPage: 1),
    itemBuilder: (_, i) {
      String vidKey = videObj.results[i].key;
      String thumbPath = 'https://image.api.playstation.com/vulcan/img/cfn/11307uYG0CXzRuA9aryByTHYrQLFz-HVQ3VVl7aAysxK15HMpqjkAIcC_R5vdfZt52hAXQNHoYhSuoSq_46_MT_tDBcLu49I.png';
      
      ListView.builder(
        padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8),
        itemCount: listseasons.length,
        itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
          return Text(listseasons[index].name);
      });

      return Transform.scale(
        scale: i == _index ? 1 : 1,
        child: new InkWell(
        onTap: () {
          launch(videoPath);
        },
        child: Card(
          clipBehavior: Clip.antiAlias,
          child: Column(
            children: [
              Image.network(thumbPath,
              fit: BoxFit.cover,
          ),
          ListTile(
            title: Text(videObj.results[i].name),
          ),
         ],
        )
       ),
      ),
    );
   },
  ),
```

Answer (score 0):

I try to answer but imo lot of missing pieces in your code.
You can get widget height using keys.

```
GlobalKey globalKey = GlobalKey();
```

Then pass it to child
example:

```
Container(key: globalKey, ... rest of the stuff)
```

And then in your code you can use:
`globalKey.currentContext.size.height`